# What if I insert my GTX 1080ti in the second silver PCIe slot

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

I have an [Asus Prime X299-Deluxe](https://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards/PRIME-X299-DELUXE/) motherboard but, due to my cooler ([be quiet! Dark Rock TF](https://www.bequiet.com/en/cpucooler/572)), I can't insert the GTX 1080 ti graphics card in the first PCIe slot.

So, will installing it in the second 16x PCIe slot (third physical slot) hurt the performance? I am confused with the lanes stuff. The CPU is an Intel i7 7820X.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have tried rotating the cooler quarter of a turn to make sure you have it the right way round, because the be quiet! compatability checker says it should be OK on that motherboard...

According to the [manual for the Asus Prime X299 Deluxe](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA2066/PRIME_X299-DELUXE/E13088_PRIME_X299-DELUXE_UM_V2_WEB.pdf?_ga=2.221442334.785398312.1513801540-1231599184.1512504648) motherboard, and considering that you have a CPU with 28 PCIe lanes:

[image]

it should not work at all, which is, hopefully, nonsense.

As long as the video card is working on at least 8 lanes you should see no noticeable performance difference from using 16 lanes (you can search for performance comparisons).

I suggest that you try the card in slot 3 and use some utility like [HWiNFO](https://www.hwinfo.com/) to check how many PCIe lanes it is using.